How to draw border with borderRadius on track of Scrollbar?
I want to draw a scrollbar that has track with border and borderRadius.(Please see Image below)

Drawing a shape is easy, but I don't know how to achieve this with the standard Scrollbar Widget (or RawScrollbar) in flutter.
Does anyone know a way to make this happen?
I use ScrollbarTheme and set radius and boarderColor, it just draws a vertical line.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              top: 0,
              width: 300,
              height: 500,
              child: ScrollbarTheme(
                data: ScrollbarThemeData(
                  crossAxisMargin: 6,
                  thickness: WidgetStateProperty.all(8),
                  thumbColor: WidgetStateProperty.all(Colors.blue.shade300),
                  trackColor: WidgetStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
                  trackBorderColor: WidgetStateProperty.all(Colors.blue.shade200),
                  radius: const Radius.circular(8),
                ),
                child: Scrollbar(
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  thumbVisibility: true,
                  trackVisibility: true,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 300,
                      height: 1500,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Even if I struggled with RawScrollbar and set trackRadius and boarderColor, it just draws a vertical line and was not reflected borderRadius to track.
